# Getting states of dynamic elements in jQuery

Tags: jquery, dynamic

I'm building a site, where I want to use dynamic navigation - when clicking given menu items, the main menu rolls over to the right and a secondary menu appears in its former place.

```
$('.mainMenuItem').click(function(){
 $('.mainMenu').animate('properties so that item slides right');
 $('.secondaryMenu').show();
});
```

Really basic stuff. What I'd like is getting the state of the secondary menu or the position of the main menu, etc.

Already tried:

```
$('.element').is(':visible');
$('.element').css('display');
```

also

```
$('.element').offset();
```

They all work fine but they only display the initial state of the element, and don't update with the website changes while the user navigates through different pages. How do I get the actual, updated properties of an element?

ps. The whole thing is integrated into Joomla - I have no idea if that interferes with things working properly.

Thanks in advance, cheers!

Comment: The code you're trying should work. Are you waiting until the animations are complete, [using a callback](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#complete)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move your code into a function:

```
   function checkState (el) { 
       return $(el).css('display');
   }
   checkState('.element');
```

The reason why it only shows the initial state of the element, is because your values are evaluated when they are initialized (when the script or the the document finishes loading if your using `$(document).ready()`). By moving it to a function and calling it on click or any other event, the value is then evaluated when you need it.

here's an example in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zfXVm/1/

Comment: Thank you, feeling a bit dummy that I didn't figure it out by myself, works like it should now.

Comment: @galingong no problem bud!